# In Objective-C, what does this method do?

Tags: objective-c

What does this method do? Why return nil if you want the clock ref? What is the (void)clock part? Happy to delete if this is dumb. I couldn't find the terms to use to find an answer.

```
- (CMClockRef)clock
{
  (void)clock;
  return nil;
}
```

and why can't I just do:

```
- (CMClockRef)clock
{
  return CMClockGetHostTimeClock();
  // Build error: Ivar 'clock' which backs the property is not referenced in this property's accessor
}
```

Without getting an error?

Comment: The method is a property getter. A property `@property (assign) CMClockRef clock;` is declared somewhere. That property is backed up by an `ivar` called `clock`. This getter overrides the property to return `nil`. That `(void)clock;` only silences warning/error saying that the `ivar` has not been used in the getter.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Add it as answer, and I'll upvote and select it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is a property getter. A property

```
@property (assign) CMClockRef clock;
```

is declared somewhere.

That property is backed up by an ivar called `clock`. This method overrides or implements the property getter to return nil.

Statement

```
(void)clock;
```

only silences warning/error saying that the ivar has not been used in the getter.